# What is the purpose of sSyncAdapterLock in sample SyncService?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, concurrency

All of the sample SyncService code that I can find appears to be incompletely or unnecessarily synchronized.

The typical code below uses a static lock when creating the singleton instance.

```
public class SyncService extends Service {
  private static final Object sSyncAdapterLock = new Object();
  private static SyncAdapter sSyncAdapter = null;

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    synchronized (sSyncAdapterLock) {
      if (sSyncAdapter == null) {
        sSyncAdapter = new SyncAdapter(getApplicationContext(), false);
      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return sSyncAdapter.getSyncAdapterBinder();
  }
}
```

Source: http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html

The two curious things about this code are:

1. Why is a lock even needed? Isn't onCreate() always called on the main app thread?
2. If a lock is needed in onCreate() why isn't this lock used to access the instance in onBind()? FindBugs flags this as 50% synchronized.

Comment: Hey you got answer for your question ? if yes please post it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same question, I believe the answer is that the synchronization in this example code is wrong. Yes `onCreate` is always called on the main thread so no synchronization is needed there. Furthermore even though multiple threads can invoke `onBind` simultaneously that method will not be invoked until after `onCreate` has completed. So there is no need for any synchronization at all in this example code.

Answer (score 0):

`onCreate` may (in theory) be called on two different instances of `SyncService` in parallel by the Android Runtime. The lock makes sure you really only ever create a single static `SyncAdapter`.

Comment: I don't believe there is a theory that allows this. onCreate is always called on the main app thread.

Comment: Service#onCreate is always called in the process main thread before startCommand or onBind (which are also called in the process main thread). If this lock were needed, then a corresponding lock would be needed in onBind, but there is none.